# how to make idx by time using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

hy folks, i want to make idTime using query like this :

| empID | date | time | idTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 01-07-2022 | 07:30:01 | 1 |
| 10001 | 01-07-2022 | 16:30:01 | 2 |
| 10001 | 02-07-2022 | 07:30:01 | 1 |
| 10001 | 03-07-2022 | 23:30:01 | 1 |
| 10001 | 03-07-2022 | 14:30:01 | 2 |
| 10001 | 03-07-2022 | 24:30:01 | 3 |
| 10002 | 01-07-2022 | 07:30:01 | 1 |
| 10002 | 01-07-2022 | 17:30:01 | 2 |

my query SQL :

```
SELECT
  empId,
  dt,
  tm,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empId AND dt ORDER BY tm ASC)idTime
FROM
  attEmp
order by
  empId, dt ASC, tm ASC
```

but the result from this SQL is wrong.
please help me

this db fiddle url :
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jjoLU7eAzqeN3BqgPam4kz/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL-8.0 or MariaDB-10.2 is required for Window functions. [dbfiddle answer](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jjoLU7eAzqeN3BqgPam4kz/1).

`PARTITION BY empId AND dt` is the erroneous bit. `empId and dt` is an expression and the output of that expression is what is being filtered.

The correct version is to comma separate this list.

```
SELECT
  NIK,
  dt,
  tm,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIK, dt ORDER BY tm ASC)idTime
FROM
  attEmp
order by
  NIK, dt ASC, tm ASC
```